# Twitter API Wrapper for .NET to manipulate (add/delete) "Photos and Videos"

Tags: .net, twitter

Twitter API Wrapper for .NET to manipulate (add/delete pic's) "Photos and Videos"? I used "Tweetinvi", it doesn't support that. I also looked at Linq2Twitter (http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) and TweetSharp, doesn't look like they support it either.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Tweetinvi releases > 0.9.2.x supports to send tweet with images.
If you are willing to delete a media, you need to delete the tweet it is related with.

Answer (score 0):

Also please note that Tweetinvi 0.9.8.2 now support video upload.
It will be improved in the next release of Tweetinvi (0.9.9.0).